# Extjs: How to set extraparam from controller to use in the store for populating combobox value.want to set extraparam value as abc.1-cond1, abc.2-con2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

In ExtJS I want to set extraParam in a controller.
These extraParams should be used in a store.

I want to show data in my combobox based on a condition.

If condition 1 is satisfied the extraparam contains `abc.1`

Then the store loads data corresponding to a groupID to get data

..same for condition 2(abc.2).

how can i set extraparam?

//Store

```
abcStore: {
    type: 'store',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: PPA_SERVICE_BASE_URL + 'any.Service',
        paramsAsJson: true,
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        },                       
    }
}
```

//Combobox

```
xtype: 'combobox',
fieldLabel: 'Payment Stream Type',
labelWidth: 130,
width: 280,
editable: false,
margin: '0 10 0 0',
displayField: 'label',
allowBlank: false,
bind: {
    store: '{abcStore}',
}
```

//Controller - function to load data

```
loadabcData: function(newValue) {
    var me = this,
        view = me.getView(),
        viewModel = this.getViewModel(),
        store = viewModel.getStore('abcStore'),
        extraParam = {groupId: groupId};

    store.getProxy().setExtraParams(extraParams);
    store.load();
      
    // How should i further set this groupID.I want to set groupId value as abc.1 on condition1 and //abc.2 on condition 2
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it

```
loadabcData: function(condition) {
    var me = this,
        view = me.getView(),
        viewModel = this.getViewModel(),
        store = viewModel.getStore('abcStore'),
// ==> next line does the trick
        groupId = (condition === 'Cond1') ? 'abc.1' : 'abc.2',
        extraParam = {groupId: groupId};

    store.getProxy().setExtraParams(extraParams);
    store.load();
      
    // How should i further set this groupID.I want to set groupId value as abc.1 on condition1 and //abc.2 on condition 2
},
```